# Possible to display Qt in an iFrame on Chrome Browser

Tags: html, qt, google-chrome, iframe

Not sure if this is an appropriate question for Stack but I have an application that runs in QT (KDE System Guard).   I want this to aggregate into a browser window with a lot of my other monitoring systems.  I know typically I would just throw down an iFrame for something such as:

```
  <iframe src="http://pathToMyNetworkMonitors.com"></iframe>
```

But since QT runs in it's own browser I'm not sure if I can do this.  I'm wondering if anyone out there has tried this or some other work around. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A Qt application does not run 'in a browser', it is a native application just like any other. It does not (typically) have a web server, nor does it (typically) have a way to integrate with a web server, so its output is not something that a web browser can access.

You may be confused because some Qt applications use Webkit (qtwebkit) to present a webpage as part of their ui, but that is not how all Qt applications are.

There is the emscripten-qt project, which ports the Qt toolkit to emscripten, allowing many Qt apps to be compiled to run inside the browser. I doubt, however, that ksysguard can be made fully functional with that.

Comment: Actually I'm not confused at all.  I didn't know the answer so I simply asked the question.  But perhaps you know of something similar to KsysGuard that does run in the browser?  I already have Nagios XI, Cacti, NTOP (which is Nagios), Opsview(again nagios), and Zabbix running ... yes I know that's overkill.  The reaons we like Ksysguard is because the granularity can be dropped really low giving us real time graphs (approximately every once 1/2 seconds...once every 1 second with drawing time).  I could make something but it wouldn't hold the weight of Ksysguard with other network admins.

Answer (score 0):

You could go and find the source for the Qt app in question and rebuild it with another outlet for the information.  For example, go and add a QUdpServer...

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qudpsocket.html#details

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-broadcastsender.html

Have this UdpServer post the information you want to see, formatted for your webpage.  Initially, you probably would just have it print a current stat, or the history of the last minute of stats.  Later you could go and generate a plot using the Html 5 Canvas or something.

Make sure that port and ip address are visible on the computer you want to be able to access it on.

And now you have your system monitoring visible in a remote browser.

And once you have done all that, be sure to post your edits for the KDE community.

Hope that helps.